# Is there a way to fast forward and rewind audio in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, audio, mobile

I'm using the [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) plugin and its works fine.
But can't seem to find a way to fast-forward or rewind. so, Anyone can please help?

Answer (score 1):

You can seek the player to a specific duration with the below code:

```
  int result = await audioPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds: 1200));
```

So you can gain the fast forward with the below code, just write a logic, where the duration will increase twice.